# Trying Asynchronous Javascript, can't get it to work. UPDATED

Tags: javascript

UPDATE: I do not have a full understanding of JS promise, so I removed that code, and added an option to initiate the server process via AJAX instead of script injection, but it still BLOCKS unless I fork the php process on the server. I have replaced the code block below with an updated version of the file which allows all four methods (script injection or AJAX, and forking or non-forking). To run it requires a build of php which includes the pcntl module (the latest homebrew-accessible one seems to be 5.6).

Here is a complete php script to generate a test page for asynchronous javascript progress bars using both HTML5 and CSS implementations. The test runs without error, but I cannot get it to load the progress.js file and run it, updating the progress bars. The console updates after the interval is terminated, but nothing happens in the browser in the interim. Tested in current releases of both Firefox and Chrome with identical results.

Note: The use of heredoc syntax in the code generating the HTML is just to facilitate code folding, since my editor doesn't recognize both php and javascript syntax in the same document for that purpose.

```
<?php   //  UPDATED: 2020.05.06 - 12.36

if( isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ){
    $qry = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    if( $qry == 'pi' ) phpinfo();
    else{
        file_put_contents( 'progress.js', '' );
        header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
        if( $qry == 'fork' ){
            if( function_exists('pcntl_fork') ) $pid = pcntl_fork();
            else $pid = false;
            if( $pid === -1 ) die('could not fork');
            else if( $pid  > 0 ) file_put_contents('__fork_pid', $pid);
            else if( $pid === 0 ){
                prog('timer = 0');
                for( $x = 0; $x < 101; $x++ ){  //  Simulate a task taking an indeterminate amount of time
                    $s = rand(0,10) * 25000;    //      E.g. copying a set number of files
                    usleep( $s );               //      Timer value would reflect percentage of file transfers completed
                    prog("timer = $x");         //      Update the timer after each file is copied
                }
                if( file_exists('__fork_pid') ){
                    $pid = trim( file_get_contents('__fork_pid') );
                    unlink('__fork_pid');
                    `kill $pid`;
                }
            }
            else echo "console.log('fork failed!'); progress(0);";
        }
        else{
            prog('timer = 0');
            for( $x = 0; $x < 101; $x++ ){
                $s = rand(0,10) * 25000;
                usleep( $s );
                prog("timer = $x");
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo /* HTML OPEN */ (<<<ENDINDEX
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Async Progress Bar Test</title>
        <script>
            var prgs, timer = 0;
ENDINDEX
    ).chr(10)
    /* JS doAsyncTask */.(<<<ENDINDEX
            function doAsyncTask(fork){
                document.querySelector('#status').textContent = 'Running...';
                setTimeout( () => {
                    progress(0);
                    if( fork < 2 ) scload('index.php?'+(fork==1?'fork':'nofork'));
                    else doAJAX(fork==3?'fork':'nofork');
                }, 100,  );
                prgs = setInterval( () => {
                    progress(timer++); scload('progress.js');
                }, 250 );
                return 'doing asynchronous task...';
            }
ENDINDEX
    ).chr(10)
    /* JS doAJAX */     .(<<<ENDINDEX
            function doAJAX(opt){                  //  This method appears NOT to be non-blocking, so fails.
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.open('GET', 'index.php?'+opt, true);
                ajax.send();
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){ if (ajax.readyState == 4) progress(ajax.responseText) };
            }
ENDINDEX
    ).chr(10)
    /* JS scload */     .(<<<ENDINDEX
            function scload(src){
                if(document.querySelector('#scriptloader'))
                    document.querySelector('#scriptloader').remove();
                let s = document.createElement('script');
                s.id = 'scriptloader';
                s.setAttribute('async',true);
                s.src = src;
                document.body.appendChild(s);
            }
ENDINDEX
    ).chr(10)
    /* JS progress */   .(<<<ENDINDEX
            function progress(t=false){
                if(t!==false && parseInt(t)>=0) timer = t;
                document.querySelector('#progress').classList.toggle('hide',false);
                document.querySelector('#status').textContent = 'Running... '+timer+'%';
                if( timer >= 100 ){
                    clearInterval(prgs);
                    document.querySelector('#status').textContent = 'Complete.';
                    document.querySelector('#progress').classList.toggle('hide',true);
                    timer = 0;
                }
                document.querySelector('#progress span').style.width = timer+'%';
            }
ENDINDEX
    ).chr(10)
    /* CSS STYLE */     .(<<<ENDINDEX
        </script>
        <style>
            body { background: #fff; }
            button { display: inline-block; margin: 20px; width: 200px; height: 24px; font-weight: bold; 
                background: #eee; border-radius: 8px; }
            button:active { background: #ccc; }
            #progress { position: relative; width: 450px; height: 20px; background: #aaa; margin: 20px;
                border-radius: 10px; border: 1px inset #000; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; }
            #progress > span { position: absolute; height: 100%; background: #88f;
                box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px; }
            #status { margin: 20px; }
        </style>
    </head>
ENDINDEX
    ).chr(10)
    /* HTML BODY */     .(<<<ENDINDEX
    <body>
        <button onclick="doAsyncTask(1)">Start SCLOAD (fork)</button>
        <button onclick="doAsyncTask(0)">Start SCLOAD (no fork)</button> <br>
        <button onclick="doAsyncTask(3)">Start AJAX (fork)</button>
        <button onclick="doAsyncTask(2)">Start AJAX (no fork)</button>
        <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="progress"><span></span></div>
    </body>
</html>
ENDINDEX
    );
}

function prog($do,$complete=false){
    $action = "$do; \n";
    file_put_contents( 'progress.js', $action );
}
```

Comment: why is the resolve on the setInterval, and being returned immediately?  There doesn't seem to be anything in there to wait on for make use of that promise.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting [a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61616173/1048572) - at least I can't tell the difference

Comment: You need to clarify _what_ is being "blocked".  As far as I can see, it's behaving the way it should, and nothing is blocked.  It's just waiting.  The long running task isn't finished, so nothing is supposed to happen.  It's supposed to wait and has nothing to trigger any actions.  If you want to run other tasks to update UI or make another request concurrently, you can still do them.  The only thing that is needed is to add a timeout handler to make another request to wait for the next status update on your long running task.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the server couldn't respond to the request for progress.js while it was still processing the other task  (D'oh!). I was stuck in the notion that (like when accessing local files from a page loaded via the file: protocol) the file would just be available to the browser without the server process having to participate in the transaction. I couldn't get why the browser wouldn't *process* the contents of progress.js without waiting for the server task to complete when the browser wasn't even *getting a response* to the request for progress.js before then. Sorry!

Comment: It took taking a few days working on somethihng unrelated and coming back to see the nature of my error.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just have that script return immediately with the current progress, and just have a setInterval XHR loop polling the server for the current progress.

If you are trying to measure upload progress, https://codepen.io/PerfectIsShit/pen/zogMXP is a good demo for using the `progress` event.
`xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);`.

If you would like to have real-time updates pushed from the server, you can look into SSE/EventSource.  https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

I'm not entirely sure what problem you are solving or what you are trying to achieve, but I've outlined everything below.  It seems that you are misunderstanding what "blocking" and asynchronous refer to.  You seem to be wanting streaming and long polling behavior as a magical built-in feature of XHR and PHP pages, which is not trivially the same as being asynchronous.  This is not what asynchronous and "non-blocking" refer to.  These two terms are meant to refer to "blocking" in the sense that executing the Javascript statement `while(true){}` will "block" execution and lock up your browser, or `XHR.send('url','GET',async=false)` will cause the Javascript execution flow to stop at that statement until the XHR request completes (and also freeze the browser).

---

What you are trying to do will require XHR streaming or ReadableStream and fetch and is similar to long polling or chunked encoding polling.
Generally you would look into this when you have a need for server push. 
 You can look at SSE/EventSource and Websockets.  Another use case is for large downloads/uploads or something that requires some processing time on submission.
I do not recommend the approach you are taking, because it depends on the XHR connection being held indefinitely, which is against the general design, and the solution to the class of problems you are modeling have much simpler solutions.  If you must do this, you'll probably want to look at some libraries to do it for you.

The best approach for the problem presented in the OP would be to decide what measures progress and return that.  You can have a server daemon that updates the value which your server side API would return.  In the case of the problem in OP, you could just use $_SESSION and store the time, and use that to calculate progress.

As for the issue of "blocking", the UI pattern is usually to have some kind of "loading" indicator that persists until it times out.  You would make an asynchronous request that is waited on, and then your UI could continue to update while the request resolves and the execution of your code that depends on the data can continue.  Or it rejects, or takes too long, and you handle the error.

A Promise is like having a callback wrapped in an object.  An asynchronous function is called, and immediately returns a Promise,  This Promise can then be used to hook the completion of the asynchronous request using `.then` and `.reject`.
eg:

```
var aPromise = myAsyncFetchRequest();
function callbackHandler(fetchReturnValue){ /* take my data and do something with it*/  }
var promise2 = aPromise.then(callbackHandler);
// do stuff ... stuff that can continue to execute while the Promise resolves
// stuff that could take aPromise and pass it to other functions or add on more handlers
promise2.then(anotherCallbackHandler);
```

---

I've taken a second look, and your PHP code looks like it is the problem.  That code doesn't look like it would work.  The first request to index.php?start does not terminate.

I would highly recommend avoiding the use of script injection for data transfer unless you have a specific need that requires it.

---

I've done a quick mock demo of your code.  It seems to work fine.  I would check your network traffic to make sure the script is being downloaded.  You can place "debugger" breakpoints in your progress calls to try to see where it gets to and walk through the execution flow.
Although I'd highly recommend not using a single file for handling progress, and maybe try to create a better separation between your Javascript and HTML and PHP code.

What I've done is simulate your server side code, and replaced the script insertion's src with text being drawn from a faked file from array content.  The "logic" seems sound, if a little bit shaky.

```html
<script>

var files={};

function file_put_contents(file, x){ files[file]=x }

function progress_php($do,$complete=false){
    $action = `${$do}; \n`;
    if( $complete ) $action = "clearInterval(prgs);\n" + $action;
    file_put_contents( 'progress.js', $action );
}

var ii=0;

files['index.php?start']='progress(0);start()';
function start(){setInterval(()=> (ii++>=100?progress_php(`progress(${ii})`,true):progress_php(`progress(${ii})`)),100);
}

// dirty mock server side code
</script>
<script>
            function doAsync( task ){
                document.querySelector('#status').textContent = 'Running...';
                setTimeout( () => { scload('index.php?start') }, 100 );
                return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
                    resolve( prgs = setInterval( () => { scload('progress.js') }, 1000 ) );
                } );
            }
            </script>
    <script>
            function scload(src){
console.log(files[src]);
                if(document.querySelector('#scriptloader'))
                    document.querySelector('#scriptloader').remove();
                let s = document.createElement('script');
                s.id = 'scriptloader';
//                 s.setAttribute('async',true);
                s.text = files[src];
                document.body.appendChild(s);
            }
            </script>
    <script>
            function progress(x){
            console.log(x);
                document.querySelector('.progress').classList.toggle('hide',true);
                if( x >= 100 ){
                    x = 100;
                    document.querySelector('#status').textContent = 'Complete.';
                }
                document.querySelector('progress').value = x;
                document.querySelector('#progress span').style.width = x+'%';
                document.querySelector('.progress').classList.toggle('hide',false);
            }
            </script>
        <style>
            body { background: #fff; }
            progress { width: 500px; height: 40px; display: block; }
            .progress.hide { visibility: hidden; }
            #progress { position: relative; width: 500px; height: 20px; background: #aaa;
                border-radius: 10px; border: 1px inset #000; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; }
            #progress > span { position: absolute; height: 100%; background: #88f;
                box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="progress">
            <progress class="" value="" max="100"></progress>
            <div id="progress"><span></span></div><br>
        </div>
        <button onclick="doAsync()">Start</button>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <span id="status"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No matter what I do in the browser, whether I use script injection or AJAX, I can't get the initial call to the server to NOT block subsequent processing in the browser unless I fork the php process on the server prior to the intended activity (and the updating of progress.js).

Comment: That is because you have a long running loop at the top of your PHP script that blocks it from returning.  This is not an issue with asynchronosity as much as it is an issue with the logic of the server side code.  You'll need to decide on what you want to use to measure progress, and instead of having the script last forever, use that value on each call.  As far as AJAX, that's just friendly advice that I would recommend a refactoring and heavily discourage the method used here as unnecessary.

Comment: You could use the $_SESSION["variable"] to store a session variable, that represents the time or progress, and use that to return a value, instead of trying to persist progress in the loop.  You could also do that for the js file you write to.

Comment: The loop is a stand-in for whatever activity the user is triggering. How can I have the server perform some function unavailable from the browser and report back periodically on the status of that activity unless the server forks off that activity to a separate process?

Comment: That is not related to Javascript on the client side.  You will need to write persistent server side code, which will be outside the scope of what you are doing right now.

Comment: That's great as an alternate way to get the status report back to the browser, but that's not the question. The question is whether I can initiate activity on the server and not block the browser code without forking the server process.

Comment: Any external code called by the server process will block until it returns flow control, unless there is a fork.

Comment: If you are using simple PHP pages yes.  Generally (well, I have and most places I look) you design around that, until you need push functionality.  You can look into SSE/EventSource and Websockets.  Sounds like are trying to do something like long polling and chunked encoding transfers I guess?  You can use a ReadableStream and fetch.

Comment: Or XHR streaming.  A Promise is like having a "future callback function" wrapped in an object.

Comment: Your original code would work with streaming, if you simplify it to just send values instead of script injection.  I can create a demo for you of streaming later.  It'll be hard for me to help much more than that given the nature of the code.